# Change username in print que

Tags: printing, username

Hi I am using my Ubuntu 13.04 to print to my workplace. Everything works fine, the printer prints ok but the username shown in the print queue of the printer is the one I have on my laptop and not my actual name. I do not wish to change my username on my laptop Is there any way that I can change this to my last name? I have tried going through the settings on printers and on my cups through `http://localhost:631/` but I couldn't find and option.

Thanks